# RequireHttpsAttribute results in redirect loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security

I've created the following filter attribute...

```
public class RemoteRequireHttpsAttribute : RequireHttpsAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal)
        {
           return;
        }

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

... and added it to a base class controller at the class level. When I request an action from one of the actions on a controller that inherits from the base class I get an error message in Chrome and Firefox about too many redircts. (IE just hangs!)

> This web page has a redirect loop

Any ideas why this might happen? What seems strange is that I get the problem even if I request a page with https to begin with! I'd have thought that wouldn't require any redirects at all.

Cheers, Ian.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in the debugger?  What happens when you do?

Comment: I'm not sure how to because I'm using VS Dev server so it just stops and says it can't find a page using https.

Comment: @IanWarburton: if you remove the attribute, does the site work?  If not, the attribute is not the problem.  If it does, then add the attribute back, set a breakpoint on the if statement and the debugger should catch it.

Comment: It also strips out the port number that the dev server is on.

Comment: Yes the site works fine without it and the debugger breaks inside of the attribute. But it doesn't do the looping with dev server. (I've commented out the check for local host.)

Comment: I think it was the load balancer insulating ASP.net from the true request protocol. I added a server variables check and some custom redirect code. :)